# How do I attach gdbserver to a process at startup?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am using gdbserver to debug a remote process. I am able to attach gdbserver to the process after it has launched and is waiting for input.

However, I want to attach gdbserver to the process while it is being launched. The process is launched via a shell script and I cannot change how this process is being launched i.e. I cannot modify the shell script to launch the process via a call to gdbserver.

How do I attach gdbserver to this process as soon as it launches?

**Edit:** I am able to create a wait loop at the start of `main()`. For example a loop which waits till it finds a file at a predetermined location :

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {

    while( access("/home/username/CONTINUE", F_OK) == -1)
        sleep(1);

    /*
            ...all the rest of main()
     */

    return 0;
}
```

We can attach gdbserver while the process is busy with this loop, set breakpoints as required and say `touch /home/username/CONTINUE` to exit the loop. But this requires us to be able to access the source code, compile the binary and place it on the target machine. I am looking for a better, easier way than this.

Comment: I believe you're thinking _too complicated_ :-D. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Are you able to run systemtap on the remote system? If so, you can run Tom Tromey' s [preattach](https://github.com/tromey/gdb-helpers/blob/master/gdbhelpers/preattach.stp) to stop the new process as soon as it starts, without needing to change any source code.

Answer (score 2):

> But this requires us to be able to access the source code<sup>1</sup>, compile the binary and place it on the target machine. I am looking for a better, easier way than this.

It looks like you are working on a linux / unix like remote operating system.

If you have admin access to the remote system, the simplest way I could think of is to rename the original executable, and replace that with a shell script named like the original executable, that starts the now renamed under control of `gdbserver`.

Something like (assumed executable `/usr/bin/foo`) at the target machine:

```
root:# cd /usr/bin
root:# mv foo foo_
root:# echo "#!/bin/sh\ngdbserver /dev/com1 foo_ foo.txt" > foo
root:# chmod a+x foo
```

As it says in the `gdbserver` [man(1) page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdbserver.1.html):

> > This tells **gdbserver** to debug foo_ with an argument of foo.txt, and
> >            to communicate with GDB via `/dev/com1`.  **gdbserver** *now waits patiently*
> >            for the host GDB to communicate with it.

---

Another way I could think of without modifying the original process at all, could be a little program that monitors changes in the `/dev/proc` directory(ies), and attaches `gdbserver` at such event with the associated pid.
Though it's kind of luck then, if `gdbserver` is attached, before that process already schedules to `main()`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>You should have acces to the source code anyways for reasonable debugging with `gdb`. Though there are cases where you can just get with the (dis-)assembly code as well.</sub>